# How to force Laravel Inertia to https? And pass HSTS

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with my Laravel 9, Inertia.Js project and my cpanel hosting. The devOps say its have HSTS and should access with https, i have already setting force https on cpanel setting, but its still not work.

I have already set my APP_ENV to production and APP_URL using https.

I have try forceScheme (https) on AppServiceProvider, but its still not work

```
public function boot()
    {
        if($this->app->environment('production')) {
            URL::forceScheme('https');
        }
    }
```

Maybe there is special middleware and tutorial to force laravel inertia https?

Thanks before.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Configure your .htaccess

from

```
 RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

to

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https:/yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: I just try that sir, but still 419 error unknown. SS: https://imgur.com/a/udDldhu

Comment: 419 is csrf error. Please try to reconfigure your app to meet inertiajs documentation. [link](https://inertiajs.com/csrf-protection) what you are trying to do when opening your front page ?

Comment: i use X-XSRF-TOKEN, so documentation say its automatically send token to with axios. Im trying to login. But, its working normally if i deploy the web project to other hosting